# Form submission after a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. I do the following thing there:

1. Hide a loading animation when a big image has completed loading and show the big image.
2. Run a function that submits a form after a period of time (say 2 minutes).
3. User may still submit the form before the period (2 minutes). In this case he'll get an alert.
4. Whether user submits the form or the form is being auto-submitted, I do some task before submitting the form. I keep time passed since the big image was loaded. I keep it in a input field because I need the time passed. If user has more than 1 minute before auto submission, I show a confirmation whether the user is sure or can submit the form after sometime.

I was using a countdown timer which handled the auto-submit, but now I'm using custom count-up clock. So, I'm controlling the auto-submit. But it's not working. Here is the code that works correctly:

```
$(new Image()).on('load', function() {
    $('#loading_img').hide();
    $('#q').show();
    start_exam(get_end_time());
}).prop('src', $('#q').prop('src'))
    .each(function() { if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#footer').hide();
    $('#header').hide();
});

function start_exam(end_time){
    /**
     * Load the countdown timer. It sometimes fails to load. At this kind of situation user won't be able to see any countdown timer.
     * Everything else should work properly.
     */
    $("#timer").jCountdown({
        timeText:end_time,
        timeZone:6,
        style:"flip",
        color:"white",
        width:0,
        textGroupSpace:15,
        textSpace:0,
        reflection:true,
        reflectionOpacity:15,
        reflectionBlur:2,
        dayTextNumber:4,
        displayDay:false,
        displayHour:false,
        displayMinute:true,
        displaySecond:true,
        displayLabel:false,
        onFinish:function(){
            exam_over();
        }
    });
}

// Do stuff when time is over or examinee submits answer script
function exam_over(){
    $('#RecordExamineeForm').submit();
    alert("Time over.");
}

function get_end_time(){
    var exam_duration = <?=($exam['duration'] * MINUTE); ?>;
    $('#RecordDuration').val(exam_duration);
    var start    = new Date();
    $('#RecordStartTime').val(Math.round(start/1000));
    start.setSeconds(start.getSeconds() + exam_duration);
    var end_time = start.getFullYear() + '/' + (start.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + start.getDate();
    end_time     += ' ' + start.getHours()+ ':' + start.getMinutes();
    end_time     += ':' + start.getSeconds();
    return end_time;
}

$('#RecordExamineeForm').submit(function(){
    var now       = new Date();
    var duration  = $('#RecordDuration').val();
    var passed    = Math.round((now - new Date($('#RecordStartTime').val() * 1000)) / 1000);
    $('#RecordPassed').val(passed);
    var time_left = duration - passed;
    if(time_left > 60){
        $('#RecordValid').val(true);
        return confirm('You have more ' + Math.floor(time_left / 60) + ' minutes, will you submit now?');
    }else if(time_left >= 0){
        $('#RecordValid').val(true);
        return true;
    }else{
        $('#RecordValid').val(false);
        return true;
    }
});
```

And this is the code I'm trying now:

```
$(new Image()).on('load', function() {
    $('#loading_img').hide();
    $('#q').show();
    start_exam(get_end_time()); //submit the form after end time
}).prop('src', $('#q').prop('src'))
    .each(function() { if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');});

// Do stuff when time is over or examinee submits answer script
function exam_over(){
    $('#RecordExamineeForm').submit();
    alert("Time over.");
}
function start_exam(delay){
    console.log(delay);
    $('#RecordExamineeForm').delay(delay).submit();
}
function get_end_time(){
    var exam_duration = <?=($exam['duration'] * MINUTE); ?>;
    $('#RecordDuration').val(exam_duration);
    var start    = new Date();
    $('#RecordStartTime').val(Math.round(start/1000));
    //console.log(exam_duration);
    return exam_duration * 1000;
}
$('#RecordExamineeForm').submit(function(){
    var now       = new Date();
    var duration  = $('#RecordDuration').val();
    var passed    = Math.round((now - new Date($('#RecordStartTime').val() * 1000)) / 1000);
    $('#RecordPassed').val(passed);
    var time_left = duration - passed;
    if(time_left > 60){
        $('#RecordValid').val(true);
        return confirm('You have more ' + Math.floor(time_left / 60) + ' minutes, will you submit now?');
    }else if(time_left >= 0){
        $('#RecordValid').val(true);
        return true;
    }else{
        $('#RecordValid').val(false);
        return true;
    }
});
```

How to make this code running or how can I rearrange to perform the tasks to autosubmit the form? I also have to do the tasks I've described at the beginning of my question. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I have changed `start_exam()` to:

```
function start_exam(delay){
    setTimeout(function() {
        exam_over();
    }, delay);
}
```

And like above, `exam_over()` is:

```
function exam_over(){
    $('#RecordExamineeForm').submit();
    alert("Time over.");
}
```

But `exam_over()` is being executed two times! Can you please tell me why?

Comment: `$(new Image()).on('load' ...` will never fire as there is no source set, and nothing to load ?

Comment: It does. There is a `console.log()` in `start_exam()` function. If the event you said won't fire, I couldn't get anything in the console, but I can.

Comment: It doesn't for me, and it shouldn't either -> http://jsfiddle.net/XL5CZ/

Comment: Oh, actually it would, you're setting the source with prop(), but what a strange way to do it.

Comment: Actually the image comes as encoded, with `base64` :)

Comment: Doesn't matter, the important part is setting the source, and it's really strange to wrap `new Image` in jQuery and then use `prop` to set the source, but it works just fine, so it's not an issue here, however strange it may look, the issue is using `delay()`, which is a method for animations only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay()` is a jQuery method for the animation FX queue only, so it only works for animations, it won't work for a submit event unless you use `queue()`, but it would be easier to just use a timeout

change

```
function start_exam(delay){
    console.log(delay);
    $('#RecordExamineeForm').delay(delay).submit();
}
```

to

```
function start_exam(delay){
    console.log(delay);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#RecordExamineeForm').submit();
    }, delay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to handle the autosubmission with a setTimeout like this:

```
setTimeout(milliseconds, callback);
```

For the tasks todo before the submission you can use this:

```
<form onsubmit="tasksToDo()"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's explain a bit of how jQuery works, I'll make it simple because we don't need to go in the details.

jQuery permits you to have Queues, where you can push functions and jQuery will execute the first one. There is one Queue that always exist by default and is always running, it's the FX one. You can use it, or you can not use it as well it's up to you. The first argument of `queue()`and `delay()`is a queue name, and if is not set il will use the FX queue.

There is not much magic going here, it simple : by calling `queue(fn(){})` you will stack some function in the queue. Then if you queue is not running you will call `myQueue.start()` (or not if you're using the FX queue), so jQuery will execute the first function. That's all. of course you'll have then in the first function to call the second function when you've finished, etc... so the queue won't stop.

About `delay()` it is a kind of a template function. What it will do is just stack in your queue a function which will call the next function with a delay, like just calling `setTimeout()`.

So in your case in particular, if you really want to use jQuery queue, you'll have to do as such :

```
function start_exam(delay){
    // delaying the queue
    $('#RecordExamineeForm').delay(delay);
    // stacking the submit in the queue
    $('#RecordExamineeForm').queue(function(next){
        $('#RecordExamineeForm').submit();
        next();
    });
}
```

Don't forget to call the next function, else the queue will stop.

That said about the queues, in your case I think just using the function `setTimeout` would be enough.